# Android: enter or tab keys still enters values into the password input field using jetpack compose

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-inputtype

When I enter or tab keys still enters values into the password input field using jetpack compose.

Below is my code snippet:

```
val (focusRequester) = FocusRequester.createRefs()

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
            true
        }
        false
    }
)
```

`Tab key` and `enter key` entries from laptop keyboard via Vysor not from android keyboard.

Any suggestions are welcome here. Thanks!

**Update 1:**

Is there any way we can do for all the function keys like standards, with out using below code.

```
modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) {
           focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
      }
        false
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex, something like:

```
 val pattern = remember { Regex("^[^\\t\\n]*\$") }
 val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

 TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
                text = it
            }
        },
        singleLine = true,
        maxLines= 1,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next) }
        ),
        modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
            if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) {
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
            }
            false
        }
   )
```

Comment: please check my update 1 from my question? needed your suggestions here

Comment: @kgsharathkumar It is not clear what it doesn't work with that modifier.

Comment: yes, my question is - we hardcoded KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER here but Is there any way to identify all the function key inputs ?

Comment: For all function keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help you to clear focus after clicking on keyboard Done button.

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
       text = it
    },
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
       onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val (focusRequester) = FocusRequester.createRefs()

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
            if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
                text = it
            }
        },
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) {
           focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
      }
        false
    }
)
```