# Android: How to ignore control key input from external keyboard in textfields using jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, keyboard-events

I am entering the **password field values** from **devices with physical keyboards** (like the *emulator* and *ChromeOS*). I need to ignore when the user presses `TAB` or `ENTER` (or other special) keys, so that it is not entered directly into the text.

I would like to match the behavior of a standard AlertDialog password prompt, where pressing Enter on the physical keyboard submits the password. So, is there any better way to **ignore control keys**?

Comment: What about `onKeyEvent` via `Modifier`? You can capture any key event you want.

Comment: What is the difference with this your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73768309/android-enter-or-tab-keys-still-enters-values-into-the-password-input-field-usi/73770307#73770307

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution, where I don't have to specify each individual key that we want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work on an external keyboard, but have you tried doing something like this?

```
TextField (
        modifier = Modifier
            .onKeyEvent {
                if (it.key == Key.Tab || it.key == Key.Enter) {
                    // do want you want here
                    false // or true based on your use-case
                } else {
                    
                    true // or false based on your use-case
                }
            }
```

just a warning `Key` is under an experimental API `@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)`

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution, where I don't have to specify each individual key that we want to ignore

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `Regex` and `onKeyEvent`.

```
fun TestTextField() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val (value, onValueChange) = remember() {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val passwordRegex by rememberSaveable() {
        //this regex allows digits, and *#w+ only. Use your own regex.
        mutableStateOf(Regex("^[0-9*#w+]+$"))
    }

    fun submitPassword() {
        scope.launch {
            //do what you want
        }
    }
    TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
                if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    submitPassword()
                }
                return@onKeyEvent false
            },
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                if (!it.matches(passwordRegex)) {
                    return@TextField
                }
                onValueChange(it)
            }
    )
}
```